# using PHP Api response in Vue

Tags: php, api, vue.js, axios

I'm working on a registration system using vue & php, on my backend, I want error to stored and return to vue if no error, I want the vue to alert "registration successful".

I got the re-routing right but how do extract the errors from my api response,

in php i have

```php
if(count($error)){
echo $error;
}
 
else {
echo json_encode(["isRegistered"=>true]);

}
```

in vue I have

```
data(){
return{
...
data : {// user data goes here},
response : ""
},
}

methods: {
...
axio.post("api/register.php"  data, config)
.then((response) =>{this.response = response.data); 
//the problem
console.log(this.response);
}) ;

}
```

In only getting **Array in my
console** except when i change

```
echo $error
```

to

```
print_r($error)
```

in php script

Comment: You can't access asynchronously set data outside a callback. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return the errors as JSON to make it consistent (and accessible)...

```
echo json_encode(['errors' => $error]);
```

You will then at least have access to the errors and you can decide how to display them.